# Preserve Folder Structure State With CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Is it possible to preserve the folder structure expand/collapse state upon running `pod install / update`? Whenever I run the command to update my Pods with my project open, it will collapse all my folders. I'm running XCode 6.1.1.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I don't think it's currently possible but hopefully we'll find a solution :(